# Using $elemMatch with value from document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm having some issues where I try to use elemMatch in an aggregation pipeline.

I have this document (I've removed all unecessary noise)

```
{
  "_id": { "$binary": "UUVDF2zrr0GPoab2ANKyHA==", "$type": "03" },
  "Roles": {
    "_id": { "$binary": "k9b3LmRO7USO6YljYSnrCA==", "$type": "03" },
    "IsMandatory": true
  },
  "Employees": {
    "_id": { "$binary": "ycVu1XzEcEyQDKb/AMHo6g==", "$type": "03" },
    "RoleContexts": [
      {
        "TraineeRoleId": { "$binary": "k9b3LmRO7USO6YljYSnrCA==", "$type": "03"},
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And I would like to remove non-matches from the result by using this `$match` pipeline:

```
{
    $and: [
        { "Roles.IsMandatory": true },
        { 
            "Employees.RoleContexts": {
                $elemMatch: {
                    "TraineeRoleId": "$Roles._id"
                }                
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The expected result would be the that the aforementioned document is matched.

However I get no results, it seems that the `$Roles._id` is not working.
When I hardcode then `_id` value it works.

I've looked at the documentation, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You need to use `$expr` to match two fields from the same document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) can build query expressions that compare fields from the same document in a match condition.

```
{
  $and: [
    {
      "Roles.IsMandatory": true
    },
    {
      $expr: {
        $in: [
          "$Roles._id",
          "$Employees.RoleContexts.TraineeRoleId"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Oguj9RgoO9I)